# Hot to replace newline characters with a string in sed

Tags: sed

First, this is not a duplicate of, e.g., [How can I replace each newline (\n) with a space using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)

What I want is to **exactly** replace every newline (`\n`) in a string, like so:

- ```sh
  printf '%s' $'' | sed '...; s/\n/\\&/g'
  ```

  should result in *the empty string*
- ```sh
  printf '%s' $'a' | sed '...; s/\n/\\&/g'
  ```

  should result in `a` *(not followed by a newline)*
- ```sh
  printf '%s' $'a\n' | sed '...; s/\n/\\&/g'
  ```

  should result in

  ```
  a\
  ```

  *(the trailing `\n` of the final line should be replaced, too)*

A solution like `:a;N;$!ba; s/\n/\\&/g` from the other question doesn't do that properly:

```sh
printf '%s' $'' | sed ':a;N;$!ba; s/\n/\\&/g' | hd
```

works;

```sh
printf '%s' $'a' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\&/g' | hd
00000000  61                                                |a|
00000001
```

works;

```sh
printf '%s' $'a\nb' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\&/g' | hd
00000000  61 5c 0a 62                                       |a\.b|
00000004
```

works;

**but** when there's a trailing `\n` on the last line

```sh
printf '%s' $'a\nb\n' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\\&/g' | hd
00000000  61 5c 0a 62 0a                                    |a\.b.|
00000005
```

it doesn't get quoted.

Comment: Your last non-working example is just a copy of the last working one, btw.

Comment: `but when there's a trailing` There is no trailing newline in the example presented..

Comment: @Shawn indeed... copy&paste error. I've corrected it.

Comment: Perhaps look at the problem from a different angle. Using GNU sed `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/$/\\/mg' file`?

Comment: You mentioned in a comment wanting to stay POSIX compliant but none of your `printf` examples except the last one produce POSIX-compliant output since they don't have a terminating newline so what you're asking sed for is behavior that isn't defined by POSIX.

Comment: @EdMorton true, but the printfs are just a convenient way for me to generate the input strings. In my use case the strings might come e.g. from a file.
Also, it seems that sooner or later $'…' will be standardised in POSIX.

Comment: @potong that doesn't seem to work as desired, e.g. when the input is $'a\n', the newline isn't quoted. OTOH, when the input is $'a\nb' a final \ is wrongly adde after the b.

Comment: @calestyo I understand that but it's irrelevant - my point is that, however you generate it, a string without a terminating newline is not a valid text line and therefore not a valid text file per POSIX and so what any text-processing tool (e.g. awk and sed) does with that input is undefined behavior per POSIX and so saying `I'd like to stay POSIX compliant` isn't really applicable to what you're trying to do as, again, what you're trying to do simply isn't defined by POSIX.

Answer (score 3):

Easier to use `perl` than `sed`, since it has (by default, at least) a more straightforward treatment of the newlines in its input:

```
printf '%s'   ''  | perl -pe 's/\n/\\\n/' # Empty string
printf '%s'   a   | perl -pe 's/\n/\\\n/' # a
printf '%s\n' a   | perl -pe 's/\n/\\\n/' # a\<newline>
printf '%s\n' a b | perl -pe 's/\n/\\\n/' # a\<newline>b\<newline>
# etc
```

If your inputs aren't huge, you could use

```sh
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n/\\\n/g'
```

instead to read the entire input at once instead of line by line, which can be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks. I had found that to work myself. Just wanted to avoid another fork and do it all with sed. But it seems as (at least according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67755634/6646161) that this isn't possible with sed at all.

Answer (score 3):

> how to replace newline charackters with a string in sed

It's not possible. From sed script point of view, the trailing line missing or not makes no difference and is undetectable.

Aaaanyway, use GNU sed with `sed -z`:

```
sed -z 's/\n/\\\n/g'
```

Comment: Thanks. I've kinda already suspected that this wouldn't work with sed at all, but just wasn't totally sure. And in principle I'd like to stay POSIX compliant, so -z is something I'd rather avoid. But using the perl suggestion above works fine.

Answer (score 2):

GNU awk can use the `RT` variable to detect a missing record terminator:

```
$ printf 'a\nb\n' | gawk '{ORS=(RT != "" ? "\\" : "") RT} 1' 
a\
b\
$ printf 'a\nb' | gawk '{ORS=(RT != "" ? "\\" : "") RT} 1'
a\
b$
```

This adds a "\" before each non-empty record terminator.

Using any `awk`:

```
$ printf 'a\nb\n\n' | awk '{printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep="\\\n"}'
a\
b\
$ printf 'a\nb\n' | awk '{printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep="\\\n"}'
a\
b$
```

Or `{ cat file; echo; } | awk ...` – always add a newline to the input.